# Client is not defined at Object.<anonymous>

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hey guys I'm just learning to program a discord bot, whenever I call my bot with "node ." If you want to start, the following error message appears:

> ReferenceError: Client is not defined
> at Object. (D:\TestBot1\index.js:1:1)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1239:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1293:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1096:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:935:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:84:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

My Code is:

```
Client._validateOptions(options = this.options)
Object.Client;
const  Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = "TOKEN_HERE";
const prefix = "t/"
bot.once("ready", () => {
 console.log("BOT WENT ONLINE");
});

bot.on("message", message => {
 if(message.author.bot) return;

 if(!message.content.startWith("prefix")) return;
 if(message.content.startWith(prefix+"ping")){
    message.channel.send("PONG");
}

if(!message.content.startWith(prefix+"ping")){
    message.channel.send("WRONG COMMANDS!");
}

});

bot.login(token);
```

What can I do to solve the problem ?

I've searched a lot on the internet but couldn't find anything that solves my problem

Comment: What is the `Client._validateOptions(options = this.options) Object.Client;` at the top of the file doing?

Comment: @AllieHowe I don't know, I just tried a little bit and that made sure that fewer errors were displayed

Comment: They definitely shouldn't be there, and that's what the error is currently. I'd say take them out and go from there!

Comment: @AllieHowe If I take that out I get more error messages

Comment: Then try to fix those error messages :)

Comment: @AllieHowe I've got the code ´´´ Client._validateOptions(options = this.options) Object.Client; ´´´  out now

Comment: Your bot token is in the question. You should reset it. Anyone who has that can control your bot.

Comment: @Aurast Oh thanks I didn't even think of that

Answer (score 1):

As @AllieHowe mentioned in the comments of your question: The Problem are the first lines of your code.

```
Client._validateOptions(options = this.options) Object.Client;
```

Remove these lines, add the correct token which is generated in https://discord.com/developers/applications.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token =
  "";
const prefix = "t/";
bot.once("ready", () => {
  console.log("BOT WENT ONLINE");
});

bot.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (!message.content.startsWith("prefix")) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("PONG");
  }

  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {
    message.channel.send("WRONG COMMANDS!");
  }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Also change your `message.content.startWith` to `message.content.startsWith`, do not forget the 's' in start**s**With.

Don't forget to add the Bot to your Server and give him the right bot permissions.

Then you should be able to login.

Comment: This is not possible because this causes another error message to appear

Comment: What kind of error message? Did you installed discord.js within your project?